# Можно ли оптимизировать данный код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Задача: Входные данные содержат два целых числа a и b, по одному в строке (−10^100 ⩽ a, b ⩽ 10^100). Вывести сумму чисел a и b.

Программа работает, но выглядит громоздко.

Можно ли как-то уменьшить или ускорить работу программы?

```py
def addition(a, b:str): #сложение
    A = []
    B = []
    for i in a:
        A.append(int(i))
    for i in b:
        B.append(int(i))
    if len(A)>len(B):
        B = [0] * (len(A) - len(B)) + B
    else:
        A = [0] * (len(B) - len(A)) + A
    C = [0] * (len(A) + 1)
    for i in range(len(A), 0, -1):
        s = A[i-1] + B[i-1] + C[i]
        a = s // 10
        b = s % 10
        C[i] = b
        C[i-1] = a
    return C

def subtraction(a, b:str): #вычитание
    A = []
    B = []
    for i in a:
        A.append(int(i))
    for i in b:
        B.append(int(i))
    B = [0] * (len(A) - len(B)) + B
    C = [0] * len(A)
    for i in range(len(A) - 1, -1, -1):
        if A[i] < B[i]:
            k = i - 1
            while A[k] == 0:
                A[k] = 9
                k -= 1
            A[k] -= 1
            A[i] += 10
        C[i] = A[i] - B[i]
    return C

def deliting(C:list): #удаление лишних нулей в начале числа
    while C[0] == 0:
        C.pop(0)
    for i in range(len(C)):
        print(C[i], end='')

def comparison(a, b:str): #сравнение
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return (a, b, 1)
    elif len(a) < len(b):
        return (b, a, 2)
    else:
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i] > b[i]:
                return (a, b, 1)
            elif a[i] < b[i]:
                return (b, a, 2)

a = input()
b = input()

if len(a) < 10 and len(b) < 10:
    print(int(a)+int(b))
elif a[0] != '-' and b[0] != '-':
    C = addition(a, b)
    deliting(C)
elif a[0] == '-' and b[0] != '-':
    a = a[1::]
    a, b, id = comparison(a, b)
    C = subtraction(a, b)
    if id == 1: # a>b
        print('-', end='')
        deliting(C)
    else:
        deliting(C)
elif a[0] != '-' and b[0] == '-':
    b = b[1::]
    a, b, id = comparison(a, b)
    C = subtraction(a, b)
    if id == 2: # a<b
        print('-', end='')
        deliting(C)
    else:
        deliting(C)
else: #a[0] == '-' and b[0] == '-'
    a = a[1::]
    b = b[1::]
    addition(a,b)
    print('-', end='')
    deliting(C)
```

Comment: Я так понимаю вы хотите реализовать принудительно длинную арифметику и простые `int(a) + int(b)`, `int(a) - int(b)`, `int(a) / int(b)`, `int(a) * int(b)` вас не устроят?

Comment: `int` в python безразмерный, колесо изобретать необязательно. `print(int(input()) + int(input()))` вот и вся программа.

Comment: @AlexKrass, да, мне важен сам алгоритм, если мне будет нужно его реализовать на языке в котором тип int имеет ограничение.

Comment: @driver в большинстве языков уже есть реализованные библиотеки и велосипеды придумывать не стоит. Только если вам интересно самому написать, разобраться и только. Алгоритмы можно посмотреть в различных книгах, но обычно сложение и вычитание в универсальном варианте так и выглядят. Даже в томике Кнута я не нашел чего-то другого. Поэтому в отрыве от языке здесь мало чего можно улучшить, а используя возможности Python вы можете их не встретить в этих других языках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навскидку, без вникания в аглоритм

1

```
A = []
for i in a:
    A.append(int(i))
```

можно заменить на:

```
A = list(map(int, a))
```

2

```
if len(A) > len(B):
    B = [0] * (len(A) - len(B)) + B
else:
    A = [0] * (len(B) - len(A)) + A
C = [0] * (len(A) + 1)
for i in range(len(A), 0, -1):
```

можно заменить на однократное вычисление len:

```
la = len(A)
lb = len(B)
if la > lb:
    B = [0] * (la - lb) + B
    ...
```

3

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > b[i]:
        return (a, b, 1)
    elif a[i] < b[i]:
        return (b, a, 2)
```

не использовать индексы

```
for a1, b1 in zip(a, b):
    if a1 > b1:
        return (a, b, 1)
    elif a1 == b1:
        pass  # '==' по идее быстрее '<', т.е. этой добавление этого elif возможно ускорит
    else:
        return (b, a, 2)
```